# Angular handle not so Rest API

Tags: angularjs, api, rest

I wanted to ask what is the best way to communicate with a complex API. Such that you can't get away with only $resource. I have an API for a game whose object has other object and those objects have their actions (exmpl. user->army->marchTo). So should I just specify each with a $http calls or is this a sign of a bad API and should be redone? (P.S. this is a legacy project so not sure what is better). And since I have another question on the same topic might as well put it here: why do $http and $resource return promises in differently nested way? What I mean is if you want to get the response from $resource it has to be written (if it was defined inside a factory)

```
someResourceFactory.get().$promise.then(function(){})...etc
```

And while using $http it can be done:

```
someHttpFactory.get().then(function(){})...etc
```

In advance thanks for any help or suggestions.